# Efficient way to iterate through df rows

Tags: python, dataframe, memory-efficient

I am trying to generate last day of the month for a date field in my `dataframe`:
so there is field start date, I want to add say 5 columns like
`nep_0`, `nep_1`, `nep_2`, `nep_3`, `nep_4`.

So for `nep_0` logic is as below:
last day ( policy start date+ relative months (0))

For `nep_1`:
last day(policy start date+ relative months (1)).

Was using this:
`date_after_month =pol_start_date + relativedelta(months=i)           nep_date=datetime.datetime(date_after_month.year,date_after_month.month,calendar.monthrange(date_after_month.year, date_after_month.month)[1])`

But this used to iterate through each row of  the data frame. My data frame has 1.5 million rows and it is taking a lot of time. can you tell me a better way to achieve the same. may  be using apply or map.

I would also like these columns (`nep_0`, `nep_1`) to be created dynamically as in not passing relative months argument of 0,1,2,. they should also be looped through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`MonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd)** and **[`rollforward`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.rollforward.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.rollforward)**:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
from datetime import datetime

month_count = 5 #define count of months here
cols = ["nep_" + str(i) for i in range(month_count)] #['nep_0', 'nep_1', 'nep_2', 'nep_3', 'nep_4']

for n,i in enumerate(cols):
    if i == 'nep_0':
        df[i] = df["dates"].apply(lambda x: MonthEnd().rollforward(x)) #get current month's last day.
    else:
        df[i] = df["nep_0"] + MonthEnd(n)
```

**Testing:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"dates":[datetime(2023,10,31),datetime(2023,10,30)]})
'''
       dates
0 2023-10-31
1 2023-10-30
'''
```

Now let's use Monthend:

```
for n,i in enumerate(cols):
    if i == 'nep_0':
        df[i] = df["dates"].apply(lambda x: MonthEnd().rollforward(x)) #get current month's last day.
    else:
        df[i] = df["nep_0"] + MonthEnd(n)
```

**Out:**:

```
       dates      nep_0      nep_1      nep_2      nep_3      nep_4
0 2023-10-31 2023-10-31 2023-11-30 2023-12-31 2024-01-31 2024-02-29
1 2023-10-30 2023-10-31 2023-11-30 2023-12-31 2024-01-31 2024-02-29
```

Comment: This works on all except for border line cases.
if i use the same for month end dates, it should give me same date, when calculating nep_0. but it is giving me last day of next month.
If i try the same by adding just Monthend(n). for nep_1 with month starting date, it is giving me last day of the same month

Comment: Okey. I've edited my answer. Can you check it?